# AttributeError when trying to rename columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, attributes

So I tried to rename columns so that it looks cleaner when it outputs in Jupyter notebook:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'i_Team':'I Team', 'Full_Name':'Full Name'}, inplace = True)
```

But I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'rename'

Any idea what could be causing the issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then `df` is not a pandas object

Comment: @bigbounty is there any way to convert it to a pandas object?

Comment: remove `inplace = True`.

Comment: @HenryYik Just tried that but unfortunately I'm getting the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `df` is not a dataframe object but a `Styler` object. First convert it into the dataframe object using:

```
final_df = df.data
```

then apply,

```
final_df.rename(columns={'i_Team':'I Team', 'Full_Name':'Full Name'}, inplace = True)
```

Also, please note that you need not re-assign to original variable when using `inplace=True`